# Why is ax.set_xlim([0, dur]) printing the range to the terminal?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am plotting a large plot with 12 subplots, and I noticed a new output from the program to the terminal that is not caused by the program or its dependencies.

After commenting out each of my graphs, I saw that it was coming from a subplot's ax.set_xlim([0, dur]) command. No other plot I have made causes the x-axis limit to print, so I am very confused.

Below is a compressed version of the plot I am making:

```
fig = plt.figure(3)
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
fig.set_size_inches(10, 12)
fig.tight_layout()

# r
ax12 = plt.subplot(6,2,8)
ax12.grid(linestyle='--',linewidth=1.25)
ax12.set(ylabel = r'$r$ ($^\circ$/s)')
ax12.plot(t_steps[0:i], X[0:i,8]*57.3, 'b')
ax12.set_xlim([0, dur])
```

In the terminal, I get:

```
(0.0, 130.0)
```

I am still relatively new to python but I can't find this online anywhere.

Comment: Are you running this in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @jared I am. No other axis does this though which is confusing

Comment: If you don't want the return value of  `set_xlim`, then `ax12.set_xlim([0, dur]);`?

Comment: @BigBen Yes! That makes perfect sense. I didn't realize that the last line of a cell automatically prints in Jupyter, so it answers a lot of questions for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running code in a Jupyter notebook, if the last line of a cell returns something (such as a function that returns a value or just writing a variable), the that return value will be printed out.

In this case, calling `ax.set_xlim` returns a `tuple` of the limits. Since it is the last line in that cell, the return is printed to the console.

As @[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) suggested, to suppress the output, you can place a semicolon at the end of the line.